# Terraform code in AWS deploys instance but not not running bash script

Tags: terraform, amazon-ec2, linux, bash

I have Terraform code in AWS deploying an instance but not not running bash script. Script runs updates, deploys apache, creates small page etc. I can connect to instance after it's deployed, but there is no /var/www folder, so this tells me the script is not being run. Manually entering the commands works, just not with script.
Any assistance is appreciated!

This was shared with me from Hashicorp forum about AWS Linux AMIs.....
*From some web searching I learned that ami-0742b4e673072066f is an Amazon Linux 2 AMI, and
Amazon Linux 2 uses cloud-init for system initialization. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2/ug/amazon-linux-cloud-init.html, so your user_data content will be interpreted by cloud-init.
This is unfortunately more a cloud-init problem than a Terraform problem, since Terraform’s responsibility here is only to send the script you wrote to the AWS API. The script execution is done by cloud-init when your instance is booting.
Therefore you might get some more information by following the guide How to debug cloud-init.
Folks in this forum might still be able to offer suggestions about cloud-init, but since this is not really a Terraform-specific problem it might help to also ask this question in a cloud-init-specific forum, or in a more general forum where participants are more likely to be familiar with cloud-init, such as DevOps StackExchange.*

From what I'm reading "ALL" AWS Linux AMIs push it's own cloud-init. If that's correct how do I troubleshoot to fix this?

Here's my Terraform code and bash script.

**c1-versions.tf
Terraform Block**
[image]

**c2-ec2instance.tf
[image]

**app1-install.sh**
[image]